PowerApps Form - Multi Select People Picker Field - How to split these values into two separate Text Labels
I have a PowerApps form (customized SP form), where I have a multi-select people picker field (Approvers) - The user may select up to 2 Approvers.  I also have two text labels beneath it.  I want to populate those text fields with the Display Names of both people identified in that People-Picker.  The Approval flows don't quite work for my requirements, so I'm having the Approver(s) navigate back to the form to provide a response via Radio buttons.  And I want them to have their own Approval sections - with their names displayed in Text Labels.  I'm not sure if this would be the "Ungroup" or "Split" functions...or something else.
Any help would be great.
Thank you!

you can use a formula like this (I named the control "MultiPeopleValue"):
First(MultiPeopleValue.SelectedItems).DisplayName

or
Last(MultiPeopleValue.SelectedItems).DisplayName


You can use all the elements of the Person object.


If that resolved your issue, please mark the answer as described in the [tour]. If it didn't, please leave a comment, so I can follow up.

Perfect.  Thank you so much!
